# function not returning any value and not raising exception

Tags: postgresql

The below function neither returning the value nor raising the exception.

```
create or replace function get_custid(p_customerNum varchar2) 
RETURNS text AS $$
DECLARE
cust_id customer.customer_num%TYPE;
begin
raise notice '%', message_text;
select customer_num into cust_id
from customer
where customer_num = p_customerNum;
return cust_id;
exception
when OTHERS then
raise notice '%', message_text;
raise;
end $$ language plpgsql;


select get_custid('Ab12345') from dual;
```

-- the customer number is existed but not returning any rows.

```
select get_custid('DDDDDDD') from dual;
```

-- the customer number is not existed but not going to exception block

Comment: There's no reason why it would ever go into the exception block, because there is nothing in that code which would generate an exception. Then if it's truly returning no rows, vs NULL, then what is `dual`? Does `SELECT * FROM dual` return any rows? If not then you'll get nothing from your query either as your function is never executed.

Comment: SELECT * FROM dual -- not returning any rows . I have executed as select get_custid('Ab12345') its returning rows. Where as select get_custid('DDDDDDD') no data existed for 'DDDDDDD' but not raising exception returning NULL. Please help me.

Comment: 'FROM DUAL' term is an Oracle one. Maybe I am wrong but I do not think that is existing in postgresql...

Comment: Why the "dual" nonsense?

Answer (score 0):

I think that is you really use postgresql this code is more likely what you need (or at list it's running...)

```
create table customer (cust_id int, customer_num varchar);
insert into customer values (1, 'Ab12345');

drop function get_custid(varchar);
create or replace function get_custid(p_customerNum varchar) 
RETURNS int AS $$
DECLARE
out_cust_id int;
begin
    --raise notice '%', message_text;

    select cust_id into out_cust_id
    from customer
    where customer_num = p_customerNum;

    if out_cust_id is null
    then raise exception 'your exception';
    end if;
    return out_cust_id;

end $$ language plpgsql;

select get_custid('Ab12345');
```

Comment: Hi aisus,Thanks for your code.  I have executed your code. But If I execute this query select get_custid('test'); -- Returning NULL .It's not raising exception. I want to raise exception.Please help me.

Comment: Do not forget to validate the answer if it suits your need ;)

Answer (score 0):

In [PL/pgSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html), `SELECT INTO` only throws an exception on the wrong number of rows if `STRICT` is specified.

```
create or replace function get_custid(p_customerNum varchar) 
RETURNS text AS $$
DECLARE
cust_id customer.customer_num%TYPE;
begin
raise notice '%', 'message_text';
select customer_num into strict cust_id
from customer
where customer_num = p_customerNum;
return cust_id;
exception
when OTHERS then
raise notice '%', 'message_text';
raise;
end $$ language plpgsql;
```